# How to write a procedure to display the contents of a table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a created a procedure as

```
create or replace procedure availability(num in number) as
begin
    delete from vehicle_count;

    insert into vehicle_count from select engine_no,count(engine_no)
    from   vehicle
    where  engine_no = num
    group by engine_no;
end;
/
```

The procedure was created successfully but now i have to write a separate query to view the contents of vehicle_count as

```
select * from vehicle_count;
```

I tried inserting the select statement into the procedure after insertion but it showed a error stating "an INTO clause is expected in the select statement".

How can I create procedure to select the required contents and display it in a single execute statement?

Table schema

vehicle(vehicle_no,engine_no,offence_count,license_status,owner_id);
vehicle_count(engine_no,engine_count);

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You have tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`

Comment: @McNets: `create or replace` is neither T-SQL nor MySQL, probably Oracle

Comment: It's not mysql and the insert from statement is also wrong. Number data type is oracle.

Comment: Where will this be called from? (Java? Another procedure?) What is your database version? If it's Oracle 12.1 or later you can use [implicit statement results](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1), but not every client will handle this automatically. Otherwise can you return a ref cursor?

Comment: why do you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this (MS SQL SERVER)-

```
 create or alter procedure availability(@num as int) as
 begin
 delete from vehicle_count;
 insert into vehicle_count
 output inserted.engine_no,inserted.count_engine_no
 select engine_no,count(engine_no) as count_engine_no
 from vehicle
 where engine_no=@num
 group by engine_no;
 end;
```

Comment: It says procedure created with compilation error. It shows                          
4/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Comment: Above syntax is for MS Sql Server.

Comment: @SreenuMurugesan Then why did you tag SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a SELECT into a PL/SQL block you should use either a SELECT INTO or a loop (if you want to print more rows).
You could use something like this:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT engine_no, engine_count
    INTO v_engine, v_count
    FROM vehicle_count
   WHERE engine_no = num;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    v_engine := NULL;
    v_count := NULL;
END;
```

v_engine and v_count are two variables. You can declare them in your procedure, and they will contain the values you want to print.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You said that the procedure you wrote (actually, you *posted* here) compiled successfully. Well, sorry to inform you - that's not true. This is not a valid syntax:

```
insert into vehicle_count from select engine_no,count(engine_no)
                          ----
                          from? Here?
```

Consider posting true information.

---

As of your question (if we suppose that that INSERT actually inserted *something* into a table):

- at the beginning, you delete everything from the table
- as SELECT counts number of rows that share the same ENGINE_NO (which is equal to the parameter NUM value), INSERT inserts none (if there's no such NUM value in the table) or maximum 1 row (because of aggregation)
- therefore, if you want to display what's in the table, all you need is a single SELECT ... INTO statement whose result is displayed with a simple DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE which will be OK if you're doing it interactively (in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD and smilar tools). Regarding table description, I'd say that ENGINE_NO should be a primary key (i.e. that not more than a single row with that ENGINE_NO value can exist in a table).

---

```
create or replace procedure availability (num in number) as
  l_engine_no     vehicle_count.engine_no%type;
  l_engine_count  vehicle_count.engine_count%type;
begin
  delete from vehicle_count;

  insert into vehicle_count (engine_no, engine_count)
    select engine_no, count(engine_no)
      from vehicle
      where engine_no = num
      group by engine_no;

  -- This query shouldn't return TOO-MANY-ROWS if ENGINE_NO is a primary key.
  -- However, it might return NO-DATA-FOUND if there's no such NUM there, so you should handle it
  select engine_no, engine_count
    into l_engine_no, l_engine_count
    from vehicle_count
    where engine_no = num;  

  dbms_output.put_line(l_engine_no ||': '|| l_engine_count);

exception
  when no_data_found then 
    dbms_output.put_line('Nothing found for ENGINE_NO = ' || num);
end;
/
```

There are numerous alternatives to that (people who posted their answers/comments before this one mentioned some of those), and the final result you'd be satisfied with depends on where you want to display that information.